# Graph with degree sequence (3,3,3,3,3,3)

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a graph with degree sequence (3,3,3,3,3,3)? I am pretty such graph does not exist since I have tried to draw one without success, but is there a way to prove it?

Comment: `RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[{3,3,3,3,3,3}]]` can be used to generate samples.

Comment: Consider a hexagon, and connect opposite vertices like a pizza.  This satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
                 *  
                /|\  
               / | \  
              *  *  *  
               \ | /  
                \|/  
                 *
```

Now connect one more vertex to the three on the horizontal midline.

By the way, the [Erdős-Gallai theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) gives you a way to determine whether any given degree sequence can be realized in a simple graph.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the vertices and edges of a triangular prism.

Answer (score 1):

The two non-isomorphic graphs with these degree sequences can be generated using `geng` which comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/).  The command is

```
geng 6 9:9 -d3 -D3
```

where we have `6` vertices, `9:9` means between 9 and 9 edges, `-d3` means minimum degree 3 and `-D3` means maximum degree 3.  These can be viewed using `showg`, but I prefer to write my own script to draw them:

[image: The two $3$-regular graphs on $6$ vertices]